# Путь к скрипту JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подключаю файл, который находится по этому пути `mat/js/jquery.timeago.min.js` и он прекрасно работает на главной странице сайта.

Но стоит перейти на другую страницу, и скрипт перестает работать.

Если скрипт переместить в корень сайта из подпапки `mat/` и прописать в `head.php` путь без `mat/`, то скрипт начинает работать на всём сайте.

Как подключить правильно файл, чтобы скрипт срабатывал на всем сайте?

Comment: Используйте абсолютный адрес от корня сайта, начиная со слэша: `/mat/js/jquery.timeago.min.js`

Comment: Я пока работаю на локальном сервере, на нем как можно правильно прописать?

Comment: хотя все сработало)) Спасибо!

Comment: @Sergiks напишите ответ. Ну, или найдите дубликат, если можете :)

Comment: @D-side добавил ответ. Похожие поискал, но что-то не обнаружил подходящего.

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы пишете путь к скрипту в таком виде:

```
mat/js/jquery.timeago.min.js
```

он называется **относительным** – относительно документа, из которого вызывается. В той же папке, что и документ (в вашем случае, в корне), ищется папка `mat`, в ней `js` – и так далее.

Если так же запросить скрипт из документа, который не в корне, а, например, в `mat`, то уже в ней, в `mat` будет разыскиваться опять папка `mat` (т.е. в этом случае `mat/mat`) и далее.

Чтобы путь не зависил от текущего документа, используйте **абсолютную** адресацию от корня сайта. Для этого начинайте путь к файлу со слеша: `/mat/js/...` Этот слеш означает, что искать надо всегда с самого «верха» сайта.

В вашем случае пишите путь к файлу так:

```
/mat/js/jquery.timeago.min.js
```